# C# data structure to get months

Tags: c#

I've got a (month of a) date written as e.g. 'MARS' which would need to return 03 (as it is the 3rd month).

Below are all my options for each month (3 languages):

```
{ "JAN", };
{ "FEV", "FEB", };
{ "MARS", "MAAR", "MÄR" };
{ "AVR", "APR" };
{ "MAI", "MEI" };
{ "JUIN", "JUN" };
{ "JUIL", "JUL" };
{ "AOUT", "AUG" };
{ "SEPT", "SEP" };
{ "OCT", "OKT" };
{ "NOV", };
{ "DEC", "DEZ" };
```

Unfortunately the C# DateTime parser doesn't recognize e.g. "MAAR" (it does recognize "MARS") so I guess I'd have to write something myself.

What is the proper way to data structure this? I was thinking of a [jagged array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays) or a list within list.

With a jagged array:

```
        string[][] jagged_array = new string[12][];
        jagged_array[0] = new string[1];
        jagged_array[0][0] = "01";
        jagged_array[0][1] = "JAN";
        jagged_array[1] = new string[2];
        jagged_array[1][0] = "02";
        jagged_array[1][1] = "FEV";
        jagged_array[1][2] = "FEB";
        jagged_array[2] = new string[3];
        jagged_array[2][0] = "03";
        jagged_array[2][1] = "MARS";
        jagged_array[2][2] = "MAAR";
        jagged_array[2][3] = "MÄR";
        jagged_array[3] = new string[2];
        jagged_array[3][0] = "04";
        jagged_array[3][1] = "AVR";
        jagged_array[3][2] = "APR";
        jagged_array[4] = new string[2];
        jagged_array[4][0] = "05";
        jagged_array[4][1] = "MAI";
        jagged_array[4][2] = "MEI";
        (...)
```

Is this the recommended way of structuring the data?
How do I access the month number (well, month string, which can be casted to number)?

Something like `get_month("MAAR")` --> should return "03". Is there an easy way to get this or do I need to loop over the individual items?

Comment: a `Dictionary <string, int>`? the key is the string you want to "parse", the value is the month number

Comment: What locale is "MAAR"?

Comment: Are you trying to parse a string that contains an entire date, or does it only contain the name of the month? If it's just the month then `Dictionary <string, int>` is good. If it's the whole date then there are other issues because depending on the culture, other parts of the date might be in different sequences. It's problematic if you have a date but don't know which culture it is. If there's a way to know what the culture is before trying to parse it, that's best.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Dutch, but it's a non-standard abbreviation of the month name. I get it like "MAAR" though... and have to parse it to the 3rd month to eventually parse it into a date.

Comment: @GianPaolo: thanks, more a Dictionary of string[] and in then, no? Since there are multiple strings for a month number.

Comment: Dictionary   ->  [...]  {"FEB",2}, {"MARS", 3}, {"MAAR", 3}, {"MÄR", 3}, { "AVR", 4 }[...] you got the idea

Comment: Thanks @J.Salas / GianPaolo. Feel free to post an answer; I'll accept.

Comment: @Pencil Is this a localization issue? Because .NET already has built-in localization capabilities. Please provide some context because it looks like you're reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @DanielMann: sort of localization issue. I'm receiving input in either Dutch, French or German, with (at least for Dutch) non-standard abbreviations like "MAAR" for March. Never seen it like this and DateTime doesn't like my input: `System.FormatException: The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A simple Dictionary can do the job

```
int GetMonthFromString(string str)
{
    var monthNames = new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    monthNames.Add("JAN", 1);

    monthNames.Add("FEB", 2);
    monthNames.Add("FEV", 2);
....
    if (!monthNames.ContainsKey(str))
        throw new ApplicationExcepion("invalid string for month"); //handle somehow an invalid string

    return monthNames[str];

}
```

Comment: `return monthNames.TryGetValue(str, out int result) ? result : throw new AgrumentException("Invalid month name", nameof(str));`